# Trying to make multiple mysql queries in one page (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to make multiple calls to mysql in one page (with Wordpress) but it works only in the first query. What I have to do?

Thanks

```
<?php
            $id = get_current_user_id();
            global $wpdb;
?>
```

```
          <?php $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM wpnu_gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_key = '9' AND entry_id = '2' ");?>
          <?php $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql); ?>
          <?php  foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>
          <p><b>Correo electrónico:</b>  <?php echo $print->meta_value;?></p>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php mysql_close($result);?>


          <?php $sql = $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT meta_value FROM wpnu_gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_key = '8' AND entry_id = '2' "); ?>
          <?php $resultb = $wpdb->get_results( $sql); ?>
          <? foreach ( $resultb as $printb )   { ?>
          <p><b>Empresa:</b>  <?php echo $printb->meta_value;?></p>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php mysql_close($resultb);?>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to close mysql connection after the request.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was the problem

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Only I had to remove the myql_close() and it worked.